# Matrix Class - Android SDK

Tags: android, matrix

In the Matrix class of the current Android SDK, there are 2 APIs which I find it hard to understand.

What are the differences between:
1.  postScale(float sx, float sy) and
2.  postScale(float sx, float sy, float px, float py)

In particular, what is the purposes of the last 2 parameters ?

Answer (score 4):

This should be the center of the [scaling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scaling_%28geometry%29). If you have the wolfram player installed, try this link for better understanding: [Understanding 2D scaling](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/Understanding2DScaling/)